# Newtons law of gravity from Wilson loops?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, gravity

Wilson Loops in Quantum field theory $W_\gamma = trPexp(\int_0^1 dt \dot\gamma_\mu A^\mu)$ for curve $\gamma(t)$ and Connection $A^\mu$ are used to define an effective force law of a theory in a Region enclosed by $\gamma$. For Quantum electrodynamics, Coulombs law can be easily derived by applying Stokes law on the Wilson Loop.

Now for gravity: The gravitational gauge Group has Connection $A^\mu = e^{\mu}_aT_a + A^\mu_{Lorentz}$ with tetrad $e^\mu_a$ and Generators of translations $T_a$ in 4-dimensional spacetime. Inserting into the Wilson Loop yields (due to commutativity of Translation operators) yields:

$W_\gamma = trPexp(\int_0^1 dt \dot\gamma_\mu A^\mu_{Lorentz} + \int_0^1 dt \dot c_aT_a)$.

Here, $\dot c_a = e^\mu_a\dot\gamma_\mu$. Would evaluating this Wilson Loop lead to Newton's law?

A gauge theory for gravity is Quantum field theory in a classical curved spacetime; therefore it is not a theory of Quantum gravity.

Comment: What do you mean by "a gauge theory for gravity"? Classically, there is an equivalence between two formulations of GR -- in terms of the metric and in terms of the tetrad. So I can't see how your theory is not a theory of Quantum Gravity.

Comment: In addition to AndrewFeldman's comment, you have to be more specific what flavour of "gauge theory of gravity" you are considering here. The standard variant of (super)gravity has both a metric fluctuation 2-field, the graviton, as well as the spin connection of local Lorentz symmetry, and it is the *graviton*, not the spin conection that mediates gravity and should therefore in some limit give Newton's law. Also, note that the "Wilson loops" for the Christoffel connection are just standard Riemannian holonomy.